# UFT/QTP Close Browsers except HP ALM

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I would like to close all open browsers except HP ALM (which is a web application) and then launch my web application.

I am using descriptive programming to close browsers but it does not close the browser process in Windows Task Manager. Also, i cannot close iexplorer.exe process as it will close HP ALM.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to shut down the browsers currently, as that will allow us to help you make changes to fix the issue

Comment: Could you please provide a new code.

Answer (score 1):

In Tools-> Optiosn -> GUI Testing -> Web check the ignoreALM option [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF8zG.png)

This way you won't need any code and does the trick

Comment: This option is already checked in my UFT. This has no affect.

Comment: It has an impact if you start UFT / Test Execution from ALM. If you open UFT and then connect to ALM manually - that will not work

Comment: That's strange, I propose to open a Ticket with MIcrofocus(If you still have Support Contract). Other than that use a simple Do Loop, Get all The Browser OBjects using the Desktop.ChildObjects method (It accepts a Description Object), and filter for the ones that do not have  HPE ALM in title or your ALM ServersURL in the Address Bar

Comment: I used the same method, after closing the browser if i look into task manager i see iexplorer process running which hinders launching of new url. So i switched to systemutil.CloseProcessByWndTitle. This method closes iexplorer process in task manager but it closes HP ALM too. No luck as of now.

Comment: you always have (nr of iexplorer windows + 1) processes open for iexplore.exe. The 1 extra process is for recovery: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2008/07/28/ie8-and-reliability/

That is like that by design, so if you use iexplore.exe and wnat to keep the HPE ALM Browser alive the clear state is the following for you: 2 iexplore.exe process and 1 alm-client.exe process